# biopython FeatureLocation comparison

Tags: biopython

I am using biopython to complete a simple task: from a specific genebank fill, extract a gene ID and related information into a table.

When I was trying to compare if the `Seq.SeqFeature.SeqFeature.location` from different `SeqFeature`, it gives me `False` every time. Even in the situation below:

```
    from Bio.SeqFeature import FeatureLocation
    location1 = FeatureLocation(0,0,strand = 1)
    location2 = FeatureLocation(0,0,strand = 1)
    print(location1 == location2) # will print False
```

Only this will give me a desired result:

```
    print(location1.start == location2.start and location1.end == location2.end and location1.strand == location2.strand) # will print True.
```

The problem was solved like this, but I am still wandering whether this is by design for some reason or the comparison method just haven't been built in yet.

Below are the process of why I come to this problem:

- First I only extracted `feat.type == 'CDS'` information from genbank file, and found
  all pseudo genes are lost.
- Then I came up with the idea by recording the information in
  `feat.type == 'gene'` and then look for either `'CDS'` or
  `'misc_feature'` to record more information for this gene.

  This creates the need of confirming the `'CDS'` or `'misc_feature'`
  is **annotated at the same location** in case there is multiple
  `'misc_feature'` annotating some domains of the same gene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am still wandering whether this is by design for some reason or the
>   comparison method just haven't been built in yet.

The answer appears to be the latter.  As far as I can tell, an `__eq__` method for `FeatureLocation` was supposed to be added in 2011 but didn't make it in.  Even other Biopython objects note the lack of ability to compare `FeatureLocation` objects in their source code comments.

**However, it's in the [source code for the *in progress, not yet released Biopython 1.70*](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/biopython-170/Bio/SeqFeature.py#L860)**

The only difference between the upcoming implementation and yours is comparison of the `ref` and `ref_db` fields which default to `None`, so if you're not using them, no problem.

For more background information, see [pull request 1309](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/1309).

Comment: Biopython 1.70 was released recently and this enhancement from Kai Blin was included. There is a little fuzziness in that special before/after positions will compare as equal.